Simultaneous removal of all noises in all channels?
Can MATLAB be able to look at all 16 channels of a bio-amplifier simultaneously and look for the common factor which is the noise which affects all channels simultaneously, and the noises removed from all channels?  If  yes. Does it mean the entire white noises of all channels are removed? But is it not white noise is random, so how can MATLAB be able to treat them as common factor and remove all the white noises?

You can calculate FFT or PSD for each channel and sum the result for all channels. The sum will give you an idea about the noise frequency range.
Then you can apply an adequate filter to remove noise. Matlab can simultaneously work with several signal and filter them in a single operation (if the filter is the same).

To the question
how can MATLAB be able to treat them as common factor and remove all the white noises?
With no more details supplied the answer is FILTERING
To the question
Can MATLAB .. look at .. 16 channels .. simultaneously and .. and the noises removed from all channels?
Yes of course MATLAB can do the software part of the job, provided that the platform MATLAB is running on is fast enough to keep pace with

data rates
processing rate

simultaneously.
It's the platform that has to be able to keep pace so at each cycle all work is done to be ready for next round of input data.
Any chance you provide some code so readers can look into this question with some more detail ?
